# In ExpressJS, get original filename of a file sent with Body Binary in Postman

Tags: node.js, express, http, request, postman

My pdf file is being sent to my server as binary data with Postman as seen [in the picture attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gp1zZ.png).

The content of the file is being parsed on my ExpressJS server with req.on((chunk) => ...) etc.

Everything is fine, except the fact that I try to obtain the original filename(highlighted in red - **valid-compressed-compressed.pdf**) on the server, but I can't find the value anywhere in the request object.

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Provide the source code in which you faced this problem. Your code would help a lot in providing you with a solution to this problem.

Comment: @DaniyalMalik I have attached the Postman screenshot. The only thing that is relevant from the source code is the `req` object itself, which I need to access and find the filename if existing. But I don't have a way to put that in here, because it's a large object that contains circular refs and functions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you cant.

If you look closely at the headers being sent with the request, there are no headers containing the filename. Therefore there are no headers you can access in express to retrieve that information. The only headers you send are Content-Type and Content-Length that gives some information about what you're sending. Other than that there's just the binary request body.

If you want to post a file and the filename you need to look into multipart/form-data ([Multer](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/multer.html)).